# Intellij tries to compile excluded java files

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

From Gradle command line, the Foo.java is excluded and will not be compiled, but Intellij still tries to compile the excluded file.

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
        
            exclude '**/Foo.java'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try mvn -> re import project.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html

As its told here ,  IDEA doesn't support including subdirectories of excluded directories, so you'll have to exclude all siblings of build/generated-sources. For example:

```
idea {
    module {
        excludeDirs = [file(".gradle")]
        ["classes", "docs", "dependency-cache", "libs", "reports", "resources", "test-results", "tmp"].each {
            excludeDirs << file("$buildDir/$it")
        }
    }
}
```

Another possible solution will be

```
idea.module {
     excludeDirs -= file(buildDir) //1
     buildDir.listFiles({d,f->f != 'generated-sources'} as FilenameFilter).each {excludeDirs += it}} //2
```

Remove buildDir from excludeDirs and then Exclude each buildDir child (except generating-source).